# How to retrieve information on a graph while building it using EditableGraph of netgraph

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt6, netgraph

I'm new to Qt and Netgraph, and I'd like to develop a Qt application with graph construction at its core. NetGraph's EditableGraph function meets my expectations and seems great. However, I also need to continuously update another structure based on the graph incrementally while it is constructed.
For instance, I want to print the nodes and arcs of the graph as they are created.

Is it possible to retrieve the graph structure during its construction by EditableGraph and process it incrementally?

Otherwise I would have to design an interactive graph construction function with this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Accessing relevant data structures

The `EditableGraph` class (like all classes derived from `Graph`) maintains several data structures to keep track of all plot elements.

- `node_positions` maps nodes to their (x, y) coordinates (their center),
- `edge_paths` maps edges to their coordinate paths,
- `node_artists` / `edge_artists` map nodes / edges to the corresponding `matplotlib.patches.PathPatch` artists,
- `node_label_artists` / `edge_label_artists` map node / edge labels to the corresponding `matplotlib.text.Text` instances.

The matplotlib patch artists can themselves be queried to determine their visual properties such as their color, e.g. `my_editable_graph_instance.node_artists[42].get_facecolor()`. The same holds for the label artists.

```py
from netgraph import EditableGraph

g = EditableGraph([(0, 1)], node_labels=True, edge_labels=True)

print(g.node_positions)
# {0: array([0.95, 0.5 ]), 1: array([0.05, 0.5 ])}

print(g.edge_paths)
# {(0, 1): array([[0.95, 0.5 ], [0.05, 0.5 ]])} 

print(g.node_artists)
# {0: <netgraph._artists.NodeArtist at 0x7f7d5d2d68e0>,
#  1: <netgraph._artists.NodeArtist at 0x7f7d5d2d6b80>}

print(g.node_artists[0].get_facecolor())
# (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

print(g.node_label_artists)
# {0: Text(0.05, 0.5, '0'), 1: Text(0.9500000000000001, 0.5, '1')}

print(g.node_label_artists[0].get_weight())
# normal

print(g.edge_artists)
# {(0, 1): <netgraph._artists.EdgeArtist at 0x7f7d0f0c89a0>}

print(g.edge_label_artists)
# {(0, 1): Text(0.5, 0.5, '(0, 1)')}
```

#### Update logic

The data structures are updated on key press [events](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/event_handling.html) (insert/+ and delete/-), but to prevent race conditions, you may want to hook into draw events instead as the canvas is redrawn after all data structures are up-to-date.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from netgraph import EditableGraph

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
g = EditableGraph([(0, 1)], ax=ax)

def trigger_update(event):
    # Here should go your logic to update your own data structures.
    # For this mock-up, we just print some information.
    print(g.node_positions)
    print(g.edge_paths)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', trigger_update)

plt.show()
```

#### Addendum:

[This project](https://github.com/GraphFilter/GraphFilter) may be of interest, as it uses Netgraph within a Qt application. I imagine they faced many of the same issues as you will / do.

Comment: 0


Thanks a lot for your answers, they are of great help to me. Hence I can use EditableGraph in my project ... nice

Comment: Now the first version of the project is finally available. May be you could find it interesting. It is used to model genetic network using Boolean Network. It can be found at : https://github.com/Franck-Delaplace/BooN